# define('QA_BASE_DIR', dirname(empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) ? __FILE__ : $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/');

Tags: php

What is the meaning of this part .'/' in php code.

```
define('QA_BASE_DIR', dirname(empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) ? __FILE__ : $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/');
```

Comment: You really asking what the purpose of the slash (`/`) at  the end is?

Comment: It means to append (using `.` ) a trailing slash (`/`) at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You are concatenating the value of a variable to a string literal. The . concatenation operator does this and the string literal (which is the slash here) has to be protected by quotes.